# How to add Pivot Table field labels to Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there a way to get the field labels to show up in the table next to the piece of data? Not having the labels here is forcing the user to have to understand what the data is supposed to be and is causing confusion.

[image]

Comment: To be honest, the easiest thing is to select the pivot table, go to the "Design" tab -> Report Layout -> Show in Tabular Form.  Admittedly the visual format of the pivot table will alter slightly, but you'll get your column headings at the top and still retain the collapsibility (although, it's worth noting that if you're pivoting off an external data source, then often times changing to the tabular layout may lose the +/- collapsibility).   There are, of course, always +es and -es to everything (if you'll excuse the pun)